# how can I overwrite __mul__ function in python

Tags: python, overwrite, operation

I wrote a class in python like this

```
class Vector(object):
def __init__(self, coordinates):
    try:
        if not coordinates:
            raise ValueError
        self.coordinates = tuple(coordinates)
        self.dimension = len(coordinates)

    except ValueError:
        raise ValueError('The coordinates must be nonempty')

    except TypeError:
        raise TypeError('The coordinates must be an iterable')

def __add__(self,v):
    v1 = np.array(self.coordinates)
    v2 = np.array(v.coordinates)
    result = v1 + v2
    return result.tolist()

def __sub__(self, other):
    v1 = np.array(self.coordinates)
    v2 = np.array(other.coordinates)
    result = v1 - v2
    return result.tolist()

def __mul__(self, other):
    return other * np.array(self.coordinates)

def multiply(self,other):
    v = Decimal(str(other)) * np.array(self.coordinates)
    return v

def __str__(self):
    return 'Vector: {}'.format(self.coordinates)


def __eq__(self, v):
    return self.coordinates == v.coordinates
```

I want to overwrite the operation `*`, so I can achieve function like:

```
3*Vector([1,2,3])=Vector([3,6,9])
```

so I tried code like this:

```
    def __mul__(self, other):
    return other * np.array(self.coordinates)
```

however, I was disappointed to notice that this function only works when

```
Vector([1,2,3])*3
```

if I wrote:

```
3*Vector([1,2,3])
```

it says:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'Vector'

How can I get the function that works both on `3*Vector([1,2,3])` and `Vector([1,2,3])*3`?

thank you so much.

Comment: You need to define `__rmul__`

Answer (score 5):

`Vector([1,2,3])*3` works because `Vector()*3` means "call the `__mul__()` function of my vector object with an `int` argument".

But `3*Vector([1,2,3])` doesn't work because that tries to call a multiplication function of an `int` object with a `Vector` argument: `int` doesn't know about your `Vector` class, so it throws an error.

You need to define an `__rmul__()` function on `Vector` to fix this.

Comment: I tried your recommendation and it works!! thank you so much!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly why [**rmul**](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rmul__) was designed.

```
class Vector(object):
    # ...
    def __rmul__(self, other):
       return self.__mul__(other)
```

Comment: although i have fulfilled this code, it seems that your code is more graceful than mine. I will take your code. thank you for your help.